# EE and Structure - View Page links don't work

Tags: structure

EE 2.7.3 (recently upgraded from v2.5.2 to v2.7.3)
Structure 3.3.14.5
PHP 5.3.3
MySQL

I recently updated from v2.5.2 to v2.7.3.  I'm now seeing in Structure that the View Page links dont work anymore.  What I mean by that is when I click the View Page button in the EE CMS, Structure page, I see the browser start to load the page (i see the loading icon in Chrome appear) but then it stops before taking me to the page.

We run the entire site under https://

Below is what one of the urls from a View Page link looks like...What do you think could be causing this issue?  Do you have any suggestions for me to try to fix it?

```
https://ourwebsite.com/system/index.php?S=aa6cefbdfb8a27770b11082fc7bd71cb&D=cp&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=structure&method=link&entry_id=322
```

Comment: I have.  I wanted to see if anyone here had run into the same issue and what was there solution.  The tricky thing here is I have the same website running on another server and everything works fine.  This completely bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by reuploading your /themes directory. When there is oddness in the CP, it's often related to missing or corrupted /themes files.

Comment: I did reupload the entire structure plugin and theme folders. That didn't change anything. I'll try uploading everything next.

Comment: Hi Anna, I just tried re-uploading the entire Themes folder and then tested the View Page links. Those links still misfire.  Have any other suggestions?

Comment: Just sent you an email. I can screenshare if you'd like and take a look.

Comment: Dont foeget to download new files as re uploading the same files can be uploading the same corrupt files.

Comment: As Stuart suggests, I've had this once or twice with plugins (not necessarily Structure), and re-downloading then uploading the plugin files fixed the problem.